# Can I ask a story-identification question about a book I didn't read?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, story-identification

During my quest to find new books to read, I stumbled upon an interesting young adult fantasy series but I forgot to bookmark the page or save that info somewhere.

However, the series had a very long Wikipedia entry and I've read enough about it back then to be able to post more details than some similar questions on this site asked by people who actually read some book in the past and who trying to identify it.

At the time being, I'm still in the 'google' part of the search process so I'm not interested to post a question right away. Still, assuming I can't find an answer, would such a question be allowed?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I see absolutely no reason why you couldn't, provided you can remember enough details to make it a good question. As far as I'm aware, there's no requirement to have read a book or seen a movie to ask questions about aspects of those works.

Comment: Yes, what he said. The key part being "to make it a good question".

Answer (score 6):

I would like to point out that this is a very good reason to ask for story identification... if you want to finally get around to reading the book (or seeing the movie), you have to know what it is first. Though, might be wise to ask for a spoiler-less response if that's the case.